# Complex regular expression to resolve

Tags: php, regex

I try to parse url with a regular expression in order to capture element, but i don't know how to do. Samples of URL :

- **location-cottage** with $path_ => array( type => cottage )
- **location-cottage-p1** with $path_ => array( type => cottage, page => p1 )
- **location-cottage-my-region-r01** with $path_ => array( type => cottage, region => r01 )
- **location-cottage-my-department-d01** with $path_ => array( type => cottage, department => d01)
- **location-cottage-my-department-d01-p1** with $path_ => array( type => cottage, department => d01, page => p1)

I would like to do this with one regular expression, but i don't know to do this, i try with this :

```
$expression = '#location-(?P<type>cottage|house)[a-z,-]*';
$expression.= '(?P<region>r[0-9]{2}|)';
$expression.= '(?P<department>d[0-9]{2}\)';
$expression.= '(?P<town>v[0-9]{5}|)';
$expression.= '[-]*(?P<page>[p0-9]*)$#';
preg_match($expression, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $path_);
```

Someone can help me ?

In a second part, if it's possible I would like to keep only 01 and not d01, only 1 and not p1, as this :

- **location-cottage-my-department-d01-p1** with $path_ => array( type => cottage, department => 01, page => 1)

Comment: Can you give an actual example of URL?

Comment: I have no idea which "element" you want to capture?

Comment: So you just want to make some parts optional? (Use `?`)

Comment: Please post the sample of the URL and what you are trying to do!

Comment: It looks like you probably want `explode('-',$path)` instead of a regex.

Comment: URL like this : http://www.***.com/location-cottage-my-region-r01

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, use `#x` to make your regex more readable. Then use `?` behind each capture group that can be optional:

```
$expression = <<< RX 
    #
      location-(?P<type>cottage|house)[a-z,-]*
      (?P<region> r[0-9]{2}|)   ?
      (?P<department> d[0-9]{2})   ?
      (?P<town> v[0-9]{5}|)   ?
      [-]*(?P<page> [p0-9]*)   ?
    $#x
RX;
```

And if you don't want to capture the `d` for example, then move it out of the named capture group, and wrap it in `(?:    )?` instead.

Comment: thank you, can you give me an example to escape the d please ?

Comment: That would be `(?: [d] (?P<department> [0-9]{2})  )?` in your case. (The `[d]` just wrapped in a char class for looks.)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of regular expressions (which are much oversized in most scenarios) you can parse the string

```
list($locationString, $type, $region, $department, $town, $page) = array_pad(explode('-', $path(), null, -6);
```

Now validate every parameter on its own (Note, that missing parameters are `null` because of `array_pad()`). Thats not even more readable, but you can modify it easier later, for example when you want to add types.

Comment: I wouldn't want use explode, because i have a succession of preg_match, and I want to resolve this problem.

Comment: Translation: I worked for hours to get this complex regex to work, I'm not going to give up now... `;)`

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but it seems, that you looked into the wrong direction for hours. Making more complex solutions, just because you can, its not a solution